# Realm conflicts with Crosswalk

Tags: android, realm, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

in my app I have to use Realm and Crosswalk libs. I have imported Realm from gradle like this:

```
Project gradle
dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"
    }
```

//----------------------

```
App module gradle
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

and Crosswalk app like a separate project ( not from gradle ).
And when I run my app it crashes with the following logs:

```
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/XWalkLib: Pre init xwalk core in com.app.myapp.LoginActivty
D/XWalkActivity: Initialize by XWalkInitializer
D/XWalkLib: DecompressTask started
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
D/XWalkLib: Reserve object class com.app.myapp.CustomView.MyXwalkView to com.app.myapp.LoginActivty
D/XWalkLib: Reserve object class com.app.myapp.LoginActivty$ResourceClient to com.app.myapp.LoginActivty
D/XWalkLib: Reserve method setResourceClient to com.app.myapp.LoginActivty
D/XWalkLib: DecompressTask finished, 0
D/XWalkLib: ActivateTask started
D/XWalkLib: Attach xwalk core
D/XWalkLib: [App Version] build:22.52.561.4, api:7, min_api:1
D/XWalkLib: [Lib Version] build:22.52.561.4, api:7, min_api:5
D/XWalkLib: Crosswalk download mode: false
D/XWalkLib: XWalk core version matched
D/XWalkLib: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.myapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.myapp-2/lib/arm64, /system/fake-libs64, /data/app/com.app.myapp-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libxwalkcore.so"
D/XWalkLib: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/data/user/0/com.app.myapp/app_xwalkcore/libxwalkcore.so" not found
D/XWalkLib: Device ABI: arm64-v8a
D/XWalkLib: org.xwalk.core not found
D/XWalkLib: org.xwalk.core64 not found
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
D/XWalkLib: ActivateTask finished, 6
D/XWalkLib: Crosswalk APK download URL: 
D/XWalkLib: HttpDownloadTask started, 
E/XWalkLib: Invalid download URL 
D/XWalkLib: HttpDownloadTask finished, -1
```

But when I delete Realm notations from gradle Crosswalk runs perfectly... So how can I use both and Realm, and Crosswalk together ?

Answer (score 1):

which ABIs of the Crosswalk are you including with your app?

from the Logcat it seems that your project is trying to look for the `arm64` version of Crosswalk library, but it can't find it in your APK.

Realm AAR comes with the following ABIs (arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86 and x86_64), so when you load the Realm library your device will select the appropriate ABI available, in our case `arm64-v8a`. I presume your Crosswalk lib doesn't include `arm64-v8a` ABI, hence the error.

Comment: You see I am using Crosswalk 32 bit version ( since I need to run my app on 32 bit deviceses too ) and without << apply plugin: 'realm-android' >> it work normally, but with that plugin it crashes. So can I run that plugin on 64 bit device with crosswalk 32 bit version ?

Comment: Please take a look at https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#couldnt-load-librealm-jniso